# Styling table with colspan - I can't make the right design

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table. It's looking in this way:
I want to show these two columns with some texts in it and after that I show company's logo. But which is the correct way to style and position them properly?

I found this way with `class="right-logo"` working, but I'm using `margin-left:-40px;` and I'm not sure it's correct.
When I use `td colspan="number of columns"`, problem is that it's not positioned as it should. There is much blank space between second text and logo and I remove it with margin-left.

Is there better way to do that?

```js
.right-logo {
                margin-left:-40px;   
            }
```

```html
  <table>
            <tr>
                <td  style="position: relative; font-size: 9px;" colspan="2">
                   
                         some text<br>
                         some text<br>
                         some text<br>
                         some text<br><br>
                        </td> <td style="position: relative; font-size: 9px;" colspan="4">
                        another text<br>
                         another text<br>
                         another text<br>
                        another text<br>
                       </div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" class="right-logo">
                  Logo
                  </td>
</tr>
//the rest of my table
```

Answer (score 1):

This what you're looking for?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Some Test</td>
    <td>another text</td>
    <td rowspan="4">Logo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Some Test</td>
    <td>another text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Some Test</td>
    <td>another text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Some Test</td>
    <td>another text</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks! I did it in this way, I removed colspan only from third td -   <td rowspan="4">logo</td> and it's fine! :)

Comment: There was spacing because I used colspan="2". :)